# Is it possible to achieve a smooth sprite animation with a fixed 60 FPS using Java 2D?

Tags: java, animation, sprites, frame-rate

I've seen a lot of different game loops, and before implementing anything complicated I decided to start with a capped 60 FPS. My run method looks like this in my game thread:

```
/**
 * Fixed Frames Per Second = 60
 */
public void run() {
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stage.render();
        }
    }, 0, 17);
}
```

The stage is a canvas, and the render method looks like this:

```
public void render() {

    BufferStrategy bufferedStrategy = this.getBufferStrategy();

    if (bufferedStrategy == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) bufferedStrategy.getDrawGraphics();

    for (Actor actor : actors) {
        graphics2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics2d.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
        graphics2d.drawImage(actor.getDrawableImage(), actor.getX(), actor.getY(), 32, 32, this);
    }

    graphics2d.dispose();
    bufferedStrategy.show();
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}
```

The only "actor" sprite is 32x32, is currently moving 1 pixel at a time, and is too slow. So I bumped it to move anywhere from 2-4 pixels at a time across the stage, but now it is chunky. Is this related to my implementation or specific to Java 2D? The movement happens while the user presses one of the arrow keys.

Comment: How come you are drawing a white rectangle for each actor? And have you actually tried displaying the fps?

Comment: I don't currently have a tile system, so the sprite will ghost if I don't provide some background fill. Are you saying the FPS is not correct?

Comment: You need to provide a background, sure, but the code should be outside of the <code>for (Actor actor : actors)</code> loop. If you only have a single actor, it doesn't make a difference, except then you shouldn't have a loop there in the first place? And about the fps, you are capping it, but that's *a maximum* frame rate, not a minimum. So first things first, actually check the frame rate...

Comment: The above example is simply an initial test of the rendering, and is by no means code complete. Eventually the levels and tiles will all be drawn separately, and there will likely be several actors. However, I don't want to get too far into it if I can already pinpoint a problem early on with the rendering strategy. Also, I can check the FPS, but the only way it wouldn't be 60 is if the rendering for a single small sprite took longer than 17ms and the TimerTask run calls bunched up.

Comment: I think you should go back to moving 1px at a time, but update the x more often.  How is the x position (actor.getX()) updated?

Comment: @nycynik Currently I'm using a custom KeyEventDispatcher, and then with each event (user holding the down arrow) it dispatches and notifies the actors. I didn't think about that, but maybe it isn't dispatching fast enough?

Comment: I would try setting it with code, have it move w/o the key as a quick way to know if that is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be related to the way you are setting the new position.  Check this answer for some code related to how to monitor key down events.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702203/keyboard-input-for-a-game-in-java

Comment: I'm going to give this a go and report back. I think this will solve the problem. I noticed in the example link that the answer solution detects the keypress and then basically animates synced to a separate adjustable interval until a different keypress.

Comment: Good Luck!  Excited to know the outcome.

Comment: Hey that was it! It is definitely much smoother and that made a big difference.

Comment: Great to hear!! Gl with your game.